# How to use NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey Or kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey?

Tags: ios, storage, data-storage

My App had been rejected because I save in-app purchase data in Documents folder on iPhone.

> Data that can be recreated but must persist for proper functioning of your app - or because customers expect it to be available for offline use - should be marked with the "do not back up" attribute. For `NSURL` objects, add the `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute to prevent the corresponding file from being backed up. For `CFURLRef` objects, use the corresponding `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` attribute.

But I want the user to use the data even if they are offline, so I'll use `kCFURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` or `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey`. What is the different between them?

The question is how to use any of them, and what will it return and how can I use this returned data?

Answer (score 5):

```
NSError *error = nil;

BOOL result = [fileURL setResourceValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error:&error];
```

Comment: and then i get the data from the url normally ?? is that's it.. what should i do with result??

Comment: More info from Apple on this: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1719/_index.html